# Capture PHP links without image links

Tags: php, dom

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
```

I am currently using the above script the capture links on a page, however what I found was there are always duplicate links. On the page, there is a picture which is linked, followed by a text link which goes to the same link. Is there an easy way to capture just the text link, not the image link?

Comment: Another option would just be to remove the duplicates from your set.  Array keys are unique and thus work well for this type of situation.  That way if the link is only used on an image you don't miss it.

Comment: `@Andy UK` did you tested all answers?

Comment: @Andy please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I was saying, I might take the approach of cleaning up the dupes in my result set.  Not sure on what you are scraping but what if the link is *only* used with an image?

You could even count the occurrences.

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$distinctLinks = [];
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $distinctLinks[$link] = (int) $distinctLinks[$link] + 1;
}
```

Comment: There will always be a link, not necessarily an image though.